# Show map using esri leaflet, with 4326 spatial reference

Tags: coordinate-system, wms, leaflet, esri-leaflet

I have this MapServer

http://geoservices.big.go.id/arcgis/rest/services/RBI/Rupabumi/MapServer

It turns out it uses 4326 spatial reference.

I want to present it using leaflet, my code so far:

```
    var map = new L.Map('map', {
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326
  }).setView([-6.1333, 106.75], 0);

  L.esri.tiledMapLayer('http://geoservices.big.go.id/arcgis/rest/services/RBI/Rupabumi/MapServer', {
    maxZoom: 14,
    minZoom: 0,
    continuousWorld: false,
    noWrap : false
  }).addTo(map);
```

But the map is not showing up. I found that http://geoservices.big.go.id/arcgis/rest/services/RBI/Rupabumi/MapServer/tile/0/20/25 will give me a tile, but the request from leaflet stops at /0/0/0. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [Esri Leaflet API Reference](http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/layers/tiled-map-layer.html):

> Your map service must be published using the Web Mercator Auxiliary
>   Sphere tiling scheme (WKID 102100/3857) and the default scale option
>   used by Google Maps, Bing Maps and ArcGIS Online. Esri Leaflet will
>   not support any other spatial reference for tile layers.

Comment: Hence setting the map option to have crs on epsg 4236 http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#defined-crs-l.crs.epsg4326 will not work? I just confused with this example: http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/non-mercator-projection.html it shows hope that we can use leaflet for non-mercator projection. Thanks

Comment: @diorahman Based on the link you provided, it seems you will need the Proj4Leaflet plugin to make it work with non-mercator projection.

Comment: based on this, http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icrs, Leaflet comes with a set of already defined CRS to use out of the box. And one of the pre-defined CRS is epsg 4236 (http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#defined-crs-l.crs.epsg4326).

Comment: @diorahman Agreed. But that is not the case for the https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet, which is a product of Esri (not Leafletjs). Event the http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/non-mercator-projection.html link you provided state "This demo should be implemented at your own risk. Esri Leaflet only supports tiles that have been published in Web Mercator Auxiliary Sphere tiling scheme (WKID 102100/3857) at the default scales and resolutions." and needs this plugin https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet to work.